# regarding the trick of using 1*1 convolution

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I once read the following statement on using 1*1 convolution, which can help connect the input and output with different dimensions:

> For example, to reduce the activation dimensions (HxW) by a factor of 2, you can use a 1x1 convolution with a stride of 2.

How to understand this example?

Comment: when you use a 1x1 convolution with stride 2, the output will be of half the dimensions since you're applying a 1x1 filter on every alternate pixel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stride of *2*. However, I wouldn't say this is a *trick*, not like a magic solution to retain information. You **will** lose half of the information. I wouldn't qualify this method as a pooling method either.

The kernel size is one pixel high and one pixel wide, and will move (*stride*) two pixels at a time. As a consequence, for every pixel there is on a row, the kernel will output a single value every two pixels, i.e. will output half the number of pixels on that row. Equivalently for the height, the kernel will completely discard half of the rows.

---

Here is the example of a 2D convolution of size *1x1* and stride *2* over a *6x6* input. On the left, the *1x1* patches in dark yellow are the successive positions of the kernel. On the right is the resulting image shaped *3x3*.

[image]

Comment: Just want to point out that OP themselves mention about using a stride of 2. Probably they were not able to visualize it properly and your illustration helps.

Comment: It is a trick in that you are misusing a function called “convolution” to do subsampling. This operation has, of course, nothing to do with a convolution.

Answer (score 0):

This is used within the ResNet identity mappings between blocks where the conv feature channels double but the spatial resolution is halved. The 1X1 conv is used to double the feature channels while stride of 2 drops alternate rows and columns as explained above by Ivan